# 'add another item' in non-CCK Drupal forms

Tags: drupal, cck, form-api

CCK for Drupal has the handy feature of allowing a single CCK field to accept multiple values via a "add another item" button that results in an array of data in the node.

I'm wondering if there's any easy way of adapting this for a non-CCK form that I'd be calling by `drupal_get_form`. I'd rather not have to re-invent the wheel with multi-step form techniques.

Anyone done this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be nice if they had included a more reduced example, but [this Introduction to AHAH in Drupal](http://drupal.org/node/348475), along with [this post on adding dynamic form elements using AHAH](http://drupal.org/node/331941) should cover pretty much all you need (which, unfortunately, is quite a bit).

The way CCK does this (mainly in `content_add_more_js()` in content.node_form.inc) is a bit more convoluted, as they need to cater for the generalization for different field types, as well as adding some extra stuff to allow for smooth tablesort Drag&Drop functionality. So unless you need the latter, I'd rather not use it as an example, as it gets a bit confusing ;)

Answer (score 3):

http://plosquare.blogspot.com/2010/02/drupal-6-adding-form-fields-dynamically.html

Answer (score 2):

Just a stub of an answer, sorry. If nobody else will give you a better answer and I have time, tomorrow I will elaborate a bit more.

I believe that functionality is done by attaching a drupal behavior (from the Drupal standard js library) to the field you are considering. If I am wrong, then it is simply an "ad-hoc" jQuery function.

However that's the easy part! ;) The tricky one, is that the functionality is achieved through AJAX and not by simply generating an extra form field client-side. This is so because the form API must regenerate the form entirely, otherwise - on submission - additional fields that where not originally sent to the browser will be simply ignored (this is intended, in order to prevent injection).

HTH at least a bit! Sorry for being so concise.